# Difference between if(x) and if(x==true) in a reactjs component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

When I was writing the ReactJs code below, I first used `if(this.state.username==true)` and did not get the result I expected.
But When I used `if(this.state.username)` it worked as I needed. Therefore, I can obviously see that there is a difference between `if(x==true)` and `if(x)`. I also know that sometimes, they can mean the same and produce the same result.
My question is if my constructor is set up as below, why would the two expressions behave differently. What is the true meaning of `if(this.state.username)` here?
Thanks for helping me understand.

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {username:""}
  }
```

The two codes are below:

```js
class MyForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {username:""}
  }
  changeName = (e) =>{
    let target = e.target;
    let name   = target.name; 
      let value  = target.value;
    this.setState ({[name]: value});
  }
  render(){
    let myHeader;
    if(this.state.username==true){
        myHeader = <h1>Hello {this.state.username}</h1>;
    }else{
        myHeader = "";
    }
    return (
      <form>
        {myHeader}
        <h1>{this.state.username}</h1>
        <p>Enter your name:</p>
        <input
          name='username'
          type="text"
          onChange = {this.changeName}
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
}   
ReactDOM.render(<MyForm />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

And

```js
class MyForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {username:""}
  }
  changeName = (e) =>{
    let target = e.target;
    let name   = target.name; 
      let value  = target.value;
    this.setState ({[name]: value});
  }
  render(){
    let myHeader;
    if(this.state.username){
        myHeader = <h1>Hello {this.state.username}</h1>;
    }else{
        myHeader = "";
    }
    return (
      <form>
        {myHeader}
        <h1>{this.state.username}</h1>
        <p>Enter your name:</p>
        <input
          name='username'
          type="text"
          onChange = {this.changeName}
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
}   
ReactDOM.render(<MyForm />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: In your question you first mention `===` operator, then `==`. Which one it really was?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

Comment: It was a typo. I meant == and not ===. Thanks for caching that. I corrected it.

Comment: Firstly, `this.state.username` is a **string**, not a **boolean**. So you shouldn't be comparing it to `true`. Secondly, if you just put `if(x)` it checks whether or not `x` is truthy. You should know about truthy and falsy cos they'll come up a lot: https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/

Answer (score 2):

`if (expr)` would be considered `true` if the `expr` is ["truthy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

`'<str>' == true` expression would be considered `true` if `<str>` equals `'1'`.

In your case it probably makes more sense to do

```
if (this.state.username !== '') {
```

References:

- https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-equality-operators
- https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-islooselyequal

Comment: How can we apply that in this case?

Comment: @ITselect what do you mean?

Comment: @ITselect—at step 10 of the *IsLooselyEqual* algorithm is *If Type(y) is Boolean, return IsLooselyEqual(x, ! ToNumber(y)).*, where *[ToNumber](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tonumber)(true)* returns 1. So the evaluation is now `<str> == 1`, which is step 6: *If Type(x) is String and Type(y)…* etc.

Comment: Oh, the other ECMA-262 uses the term [*Abstract Equality Comparison*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison) rather than [*IsLooselyEqual*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-islooselyequal), but they're the same thing.

Comment: @RobG probably ES2021 vs ES2022 change?

Comment: @zerkms—yes, ES2022 is still draft. I don't understand the need to constantly change the language, especially when it's needless name changes for internal algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

There's a difference between using `if(this.state.username==true)` and `if(this.state.username)`. Using the former compares the value of `this.state.username` with `true`, which of course is false unless it returns a string value of `1`, in which case it will return `true`. 
However, doing the latter casts `this.state.username` to boolean and checks if `this.state.username` has a value (like not `undefined`). 
So if you want to use `if(this.state.username==true)`, you will have to cast `this.state.username` to boolean first by using `!!` (or `Boolean`):

```js
if(!!this.state.username==true) {
  // your code goes here
}
```

Comment: The statement "*the former compares the value of this.state.username with true, which of course is false*" is incorrect. If *this.state.username* returns a string value "1", then the expression resolves to `true`.

Comment: @RobG Thanks for pointing that out. I edited it to make it more accurate :D

Answer (score 0):

data type `username` is not boolean but string, string validation using `!== ''`

Answer (score 0):

Haha, that is so funny. I've tried it with all truthies and falsies. Lets's see the result:

```js
console.log('Truthies:')
console.log('"a" == true           returns:', "a" == true)
console.log('"1" == true           returns:', "1" == true)
console.log('1 == true             returns:', 1 == true)
console.log('3 == true             returns:', 3 == true)
console.log('-1 == true            returns:', -1 == true)
console.log('[] == true            returns:', [] == true)
console.log('{} == true            returns:', {} == true)
console.log('function a(){return true} == true    returns:', function
a(){return true} == true)
console.log('"true" == true        returns:', "true" == true)

console.log('')
console.log('Falsies:')
console.log('NaN == false          returns:', NaN == false)
console.log('"" == false           returns:', "" == false)
console.log('`` == false           returns:', `` == false)
console.log('0 == false            returns:', 0 == false)
console.log('undefined == false    returns:', undefined == false)
console.log('null == false         returns:', null == false)


console.log('')
console.log('Truthies not-equal false:')
console.log('"a" !== false           returns:', "a" !== false)
console.log('1 !== false             returns:', 1 !== false)
console.log('"1" !== false           returns:', "1" !== false)
console.log('3 !== false             returns:', 3 !== false)
console.log('-1 !== false            returns:', -1 !== false)
console.log('[] !== false            returns:', [] !== false)
console.log('{} !== false            returns:', {} !== false)
console.log('function a(){return true} !== false     returns:', function
a(){return true} !== false)
console.log('"true" !== false         returns:', "true" !== false)

console.log('')
console.log('Truthies not-equal true:')
console.log('"a" !== true           returns:', "a" !== true)
console.log('1 !== true             returns:', 1 !== true)
console.log('"1" !== true           returns:', "1" !== true)
console.log('3 !== true             returns:', 3 !== true)
console.log('-1 !== true            returns:', -1 !== true)
console.log('[] !== true            returns:', [] !== true)
console.log('{} !== true            returns:', {} !== true)
console.log('function a(){return true} !== true     returns:', function
a(){return true} !== false)
console.log('"true" !== true         returns:', "true" !== true)
```

There are some tricky things. E.g. both `1 == true` and `1 !== true` are `true` .

Anyways... you'd better to use `!!` to stay on the safe side:

```js
const { useState } = React

const MyForm = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ username: '' })

  const handleChange = ({ target: { name, value } }) => {
    setState({ [name]: value })
  }
  
  return (
    <form>
      {!!state.username && (
        <h1>Hello {state.username}</h1>
      )}
      <p>Enter your name:</p>
      <input
        name="username"
        type="text"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </form>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyForm />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

*And you can use hooks, functional component, inline jsx operators and deconstruction for simplicity.*